# Convert jQuery to JavaScript for Google Analytics pdf download tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

Below is what i have for tracking pdf download from the site and sending beacon to GA using tealium. It works fine with the site that has jquery library on the page and but I need something similar for the site that do not have jquery library. Please guide me to convert this piece of code to JS so that the tracking works fine without using jquery library.

```
                 utag.runonce[2] = 1;
                    jQuery(document.body).on('mousedown', 'a[href$=pdf]', function(e) {
                        y = this.href;
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            var ec_cat, ea_act, el_lab;
                            var a = document.createElement('a');
                            a.href = y;
                            var z = a.pathname.substr(a.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                            el_lab = utag.data['data-assetinternalname'] || z;
                            ec_cat = utag.data['data-assettype'] || "file";
                            ea_act = utag.data['data-assetinteraction'] || "download";
                            utag.link({
                                event_category: ec_cat.toLowerCase(),
                                event_action: ea_act.toLowerCase(),
                                event_label: el_lab.toLowerCase()
                            });
                            if (typeof utag.data['data-engagementtype'] != "undefined") {
                                ga_cat = utag.data['data-engagementtype'] || "connect";
                                ga_act = utag.data['data-assettype'] || "file";
                                utag.link({
                                    event_category: ec_cat.toLowerCase(),
                                    event_action: ea_act.toLowerCase(),
                                    event_label: el_lab.toLowerCase()
                                });
                            }
                        }, 300);
```

Comment: Where's your attempt? You need `document.querySelectorAll` and `.forEach` and `.addEventListener` for this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the main (possibly only) replacement you need to do is the `jQuery.on`. Normally you'd just replace with `document.addEventListener`, but since you're using filtering it gets a little more complicated.

Here's a module I wrote some time ago and use frequently to do this:

```
  const addEvent = function(target, event, filter, callback, opts) {
    if (typeof target === 'string') target = document.querySelectorAll(target);
    if (!(target instanceof NodeList || target instanceof Array)) {
      target = [target];
    }
    if (filter) {
      var oldCb = callback;
      callback = function(e) {
        if (e.target.matches(filter)) oldCb(e);
      };
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
      target[i].addEventListener(event, callback, opts);
    }
  };
```

The way you'd call it in your example above would be like this:

```
addEvent(document.body, 'mousedown', 'a[href$=pdf]', function(e) { /*...*/ });
```